# Problem using smtplib.SMTP_SSL with yahoo as server

Tags: ssl, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send an email through python using yahoo as my server but when I do I get the error

"ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)"

I'm guessing that, as it says, my ssl version doesn't match yahoo's but I cannot find what version yahoo is using anywhere. I am using ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION to identify my version which gives it as "OpenSSL 1.1.1i"

Anyone know how I can fix this? I've included the code below

```
import smtplib

msg = "Hello!, this is a test email. Goodbye!"

fromadd = '*****@yahoo.com'
toadd = 'email@domain.com'
subject = 'Python Test Email'
username = str('*****@yahoo.com')
password = str('********')
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromadd, toadd, msg)
server.quit()
```

and the exact error message:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 587)
> ```

Port 587 is for plain SMTP, where TLS is initiated by an explicit plain text STARTTLS command (explicit TLS). For this use `smtplib.SMTP` with [starttls()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls).

To use `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` (implicit TLS, i.e. directly after TCP connect) one should connect to port 465 instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. When I use port 587 with startlls() I get ```smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed``` and when I use 465 with SMTP_SSL I get ```raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'\x02\x01Z\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x01\x00')``` but I can't find any information on SMTPConnect Error -1. Any ideas?

Comment: @jam: Works perfectly for me, both for 465 and 587. No idea what you are actually doing.

Comment: can confirm that on 587 i also get "Connection unexpectedly closed", on AOL too -- seems to be a pattern with the two Verizon/Yahoo owned providers.